# Stop PyCharm running pip as root

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv, pip

I need to create Django project in PyCharm. I'm using interpreter `3.6.3 at /usr/bin/python3.6`. After creating it, I'm getting message `Authentication is needed to run /usr/bin/python3.6 as the superuser`. I clicked cancel and I've got:

```
Executed command: pip install Django
Error occurred: Non-zero exit code (126)
Proposed solution:
   Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at '/usr/bin/python3.6'.
Command output:
   Error executing command as another user: Request dismissed
```

However, if I'll give my password and click Authenticate then pip, pip3 and virtualenv will be broken because IDE is trying to install Django as root. How can I stop PyCharm running pip as root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make PyCharm play nice with virtual environments, do the following:

#### 1 - use shell to create virtualenv

- **create** virtual environment: `virtualenv <virtualEnvName>`
- **activate** virtual environment: `. <virtualEnvName>/bin/activate`
- **download** packages into virtual environment: `pip install <pkg>`

#### 2 - tell PyCharm about virtualenv you've created

- **open project** in PyCharm: `File > Open > urProject`
- **select interpreter** from virtualenv: `PyCharm Community Edition > Preferences > Project > Project Interpreter`